# Node JS multiple request handling

Tags: node.js, multithreading, threadpool

NodeJs is single-threaded means it has one main thread that cares about our operations and for the rest of asynchronous, it gives the task to another thread.

So as per understanding callback results in offloading the current task to a separate thread.

```
app.post("/get",(req,res)=>{
   res.status(200).json({message:"Success"})
})
```

Does the above statement execute in another thread?

Comment: No. As you correctly stated nodejs is  single threaded. There are no "other threads". Read about EventLoop and Callstack for instance here https://medium.com/@Rahulx1/understanding-event-loop-call-stack-event-job-queue-in-javascript-63dcd2c71ecd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in a Javascript program runs in one thread (unless you use workers, which your example does not).

Javascript runs with a [main loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#event_loop). The main loop reads a queue of events and processes them one by one. All sorts of things turn into events in that queue: incoming web requests, timeouts, intervals, promises awaiting resolution, messages, you name it. It's more complex than this, of course.

It's good that it's all one thread: you don't have to worry about thread concurrency.

There's a downside: if you write a long-running method, its execution will block the main loop until it's finished.  This makes web pages janky and nodejs programs have slow response.  Use workers (separate threads) for that stuff.

The method in a `.post()` like yours is run in response to an event on the queue announcing an incoming web request.

Read about the main loop.